# How to remove trac cleanly?

Tags: uninstallation, trac

I need to remove Trac but I don't have enough clue.

I heard that I can simply remove all files and they are under /usr/lib

```
[root@deadwood /]# find /usr/lib -name "*trac*"
/usr/lib/python2.4/test/test_trace.pyc
/usr/lib/python2.4/test/test_traceback.pyc
/usr/lib/python2.4/test/decimaltestdata/subtract.decTest
/usr/lib/python2.4/test/test_traceback.pyo
/usr/lib/python2.4/test/test_trace.py
/usr/lib/python2.4/test/test_traceback.py
/usr/lib/python2.4/test/test_trace.pyo
/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Pygments-1.5-py2.4.egg/pygments/styles/trac.py
/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Pygments-1.5-py2.4.egg/pygments/styles/trac.pyc
/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/trac_svn.pth
```

It seems that only the last three count. Right? And I believe also these two as well?

```
/usr/bin/tracd
/usr/bin/trac-admin
```

Would this be done all right?

Comment: If you installed Trac using your package manager, don't try to uninstall it manually.  Let your package manager do the work.  If you installed via `easy_install`, don't forget to run `easy_install -m PackageName` so that Python knows that you removed the package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"If you installed Trac using your package manager, don't try to uninstall it manually. Let your package manager do the work. If you installed via easy_install, don't forget to run easy_install -m PackageName so that Python knows that you removed the package."

(Echoing bta's comment as an answer so that it can be voted upon and/or accepted.)

Also, your "find" statement was case sensitive which is why it didn't match "Trac-0.12-py2.4.egg" (capital T in 'Trac').  To match case-insensitively, use -iname instead of -name.

Answer (score 0):

Of the files in your first listing, only the last one really belongs to Trac. Perhaps you already removed/uninstalled most of the other ones? The final two files in `/usr/bin` are part of Trac, so you may remove those.

Comment: Do you know where "the other ones" are? I removed nothing yet.

Comment: I don't. You could try to find out by running `python -c 'import trac; print trac.__file__'`.

Comment: /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Trac-0.12-py2.4.egg/trac/__init__.pyc - this is the only line I got by runing it

Comment: Right, so you should also remove `/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Trac-0.12-py2.4.egg`.